# Meta programming in OpenERP

Tags: python, odoo

Here a way to develop OpenERP

```
class stock_incoterms(osv.osv):

_name = "stock.incoterms"
_description = "Incoterms"
_columns = {
    'name': fields.char('Name', size=64, required=True),
    'code': fields.char('Code', size=3, required=True),
    'active': fields.boolean('Active'),
}
_defaults = {
    'active': lambda *a: True,
}
```

stock_incoterms()
This is typical OpenERP model and map to table name stock_incoterms.
  The columns property defines columns for the table
The default property defines default value for each column.

My questions are:

> How to implement this in Python?
>     When running stock_incoterms(), OpenERP will read this model, generate the table with these defined columns.
>      After that, suppose I created a record in this table, then I ask give me the model of this class, ex
>   stock_incoterm = stock_incoterms.get(1) ( record id in db)
>   Now i can access
>   stock_incoterm.name
>   stock_incoterm.code
>   ........

This way of defining model is kind of Meta Programming but I don't know how to write it in Python.

Could anyone guide me the details behind or some good links about meta programming in Python?

Comment: Are you asking how to construct a Python class dynamically? If so, what information are you given, and in what form?

Comment: What do you want? "How do i implement *this* " with no explanation of what *this* is not a real question.

Comment: Sorry for my unclear question. I've just updated it. Hope it clearly enough.

Answer (score 2):

The [OpenERP developer book](http://doc.openerp.com/developer/index.html#book-develop-link) is the best place to start looking. It sounds like you want to add a new table called stock_incoterm. I would recommend you start a new module and add the table to it, along with a screen and some menu items to edit the table. The developer book has a chapter on [developing modules](http://doc.openerp.com/developer/2_4_module_development/index.html).

Once you've got all that set up, your code to access fields on a record would look something like this:

```
class stock_incoterms(osv.osv):
    # ...

    def do_something(self, cr, uid, ids):
        for stock_incoterm in self.browse(cr, uid, ids):
            name = stock_incoterm.name

            # ...
```

Comment: I've read this book. My purpose is how to implement thing like OpenERP. I should try to read the source code but I'd like to get a hint before diving in.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Study OpenERP's code, then :-)

Other nice starting points include:

- Logilab's [yams](http://www.logilab.org/project/yams) module and [Cubicweb](http://www.cubicweb.org/project/cubicweb)'s ORM
- Tools like [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/)

Things boil down to using Python's introspection facilities to find out the structure of the objects provided by the user and converting that structure to e.g. SQL table definitions and queries.

In `yams`, a `Schema` object is created by the user defined classes which derive from [`EntityType`](http://hg.logilab.org/yams/file/83ce375217d3/buildobjs.py) which has the `metadefinition` metaclass. This metaclass lists the class attributes of the `EntityType` and stores them in various internal fields. Then the [`schema2sql`](http://hg.logilab.org/yams/file/83ce375217d3/schema2sql.py) module can be used to serialize the schema as a set of SQL tables.